Can you explain how the update should work?
Please refer to the paper Migacz, S., et al. (2019). Parallel implementation of a sequential Markov chain in Monte Carlo simulations of physical systems with pairwise interactions. Journal of Chemical Theory and Computation, 15(5), 2797–2806.
Suppose I have $N=5$ particles: $A(1,4)$, $B(2,2)$, $C(3,1)$, $D(4,3)$, and $E(0,0)$.
Suppose $MovingSet=\{A, C, D\}$, and $FixedSet=\{B, E\}$.
$\begin{array}
{r | c | c | c | c | c}  & 
A & C & D & B & E \\ \hline 
A & \times & E_{AC} & E_{AD} & E_{AB} & E_{AE} \\ \hline 
C & - & \times & E_{CD} & E_{CB} & E_{CE} \\ \hline 
D & - & - & \times & E_{DB} & E_{DE} \\ \hline 
B & - & - & - & \times & E_{BE} \\ \hline 
E & - & - & - & - & \times \\ \hline 
\end{array}$
Here is the extracted equation $(3)$ rewritten in MathJax:
$$E_{\text{moving}}^{\text{moving}} = \sum_{i=1}^{M-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{M} E(X_i^{0 \lor 1}, X_j^{0 \lor 1})$$
$$= \sum_{i=1}^{M-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{M} \{ E(X_i^{0}, X_j^{0}) \lor E(X_i^{0}, X_j^{1}) \lor E(X_i^{1}, X_j^{0}) \lor E(X_i^{1}, X_j^{1}) \} \tag{3}$$
Eq.3 says that $$E_{(moving, moving)}^{00} =E_{AC} + E_{AD} + E_{CD} \tag{3.1}$$
Here is the extracted equation $(4)$ rewritten in MathJax:
$$E_{\text{fixed}}^{\text{moving}} = \sum_{i=1}^{M} \sum_{j=M+1}^{N} E(X_i^{0} \lor X_j^{0})$$
$$= \sum_{i=1}^{M-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{M} \{ E(X_i^{0}, X_j^{0}) \lor E(X_i^{1}, X_j^{0}) \} \tag{4}$$
Eq.4 says that $$E_{(moving, fixed)}^{00} =E_{AB} + E_{AE} + E_{CB}+ E_{CE}+ E_{DB}+ E_{DE} \tag{4.1}$$

begin
Assign randomly $M$ particles in $S$ to $\text{MovingSet}$
Assign $S \setminus \text{MovingSet}$ to $\text{StationarySet}$
/* Parallel section that fully utilises GPU */
For each particle $i$ in the $\text{MovingSet}$, generate trial configuration $X_i^1$
Compute interactions within $\text{MovingSet}$ as in Eq. 3 and update appropriate parts of arrays $E^{00}, E^{01}, E^{10},$ and $E^{11}$
Compute interactions between $\text{MovingSet}$ and $\text{StationarySet}$ as in Eq. 4 and update appropriate parts of arrays $E^{00}$ and $E^{10}$
Compute energy of each moving particle in starting and trial configurations as:
$E_i^{0} \leftarrow \sum_k E_{ik}^{00}$ and $E_i^{1} \leftarrow \sum_k E_{ik}^{01}$
/* The section that is executed within single block */
for each particle $i$ in $\text{MovingSet}$ do
...

Algorithm-1 says that we should update elements in $(3.1)$ using elements in $(4.1)$. However, it doesn't say which elements should replace which element. It also doesn't say on what condition we should replace the elements.
Also, since the dimensions of $E_{(moving, moving)}^{00}$ and $E_{(moving, fixed)}^{00}$ will be different on most occasions, I am not really sure how this update will work.
Can you explain how the update should work?
